# php extract UK postal code and validate it

Tags: php, regex, postal-code

I have some text blocks like

```
John+and+Co-Accountants-Hove-BN31GE-2959519
```

I need a function to extract the postcode "BN31GE". It may happen to not exist and have a text block without postcode so the function must also validate if the extracted text is valid postcode .

```
John+and+Co-Accountants-Hove-2959519
```

Comment: Please provide the exact format of UK postal codes

Comment: @yi_H The only comprehensive resource that I found is on wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find below code to extract valid UK postal code. It return array if post code found otherwise empty.

```
<?php
$getPostcode="";
$str="John+and+Co-Accountants-Hove-BN31GE-2959519";
$getArray = explode("-",$str);
if(is_array($getArray) && count($getArray)>0) {
    foreach($getArray as $key=>$val) {
        if(preg_match("/^(([A-PR-UW-Z]{1}[A-IK-Y]?)([0-9]?[A-HJKS-UW]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY]?|[0-9]?[0-9]?))\s?([0-9]{1}[ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})$/i",strtoupper($val),$postcode)) {
            $getPostcode = $postcode[0];
        }
    }
}
print"<pre>";
print_r($getPostcode); 
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

The UK Government Data Standard for postcodes is:

```
((GIR 0AA)|((([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][A-HJKSTUW])|([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9][ABEHMNPRVWXY])))) [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}))
```

**Edit:** I had the above in some (personal) code with a reference to a now non-existence UK government web page.  The appropriate British Standard is BS7666 and information on this is currently available [here](http://www.ispp-aggregator.org.uk/f1les/ISPP/docs/schemas/v5/bs7666-v2-0.xsd).  That lists a slightly different regex.

Comment: is not working . I think it's because in my text block the postcode doesn't have any space .

Comment: @Michael - if you change the " " to a " ?" (i.e. add a ? after the space towards the end of regex) you'll get something that optionally allows the space.

Comment: I added "?" but for some reasons still doesn't work. I've tried it agaist this text block "John+and+Co-Accountants-Hove-BN31GE-2959519"

Comment: @Michael - The above regex matches a UK postcode.  You need to use it in the appropriate place in your wider regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex: preg_grep function,

I don't know the format of english postcodes but you could go with something like:

```
(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+-)+
```

This matches

- "-Accountants-"
- "-BN31GE-"

You can then proceed at taking always the second value or you can enhance you regex to match exactly english postcodes, something like maybe

```
 ([A-Z0-9]{6})
```