# International Postal Code Validation

Tags: asp.net, regex, postal-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the ultimate postal code and zip regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578406/what-is-the-ultimate-postal-code-and-zip-regex)

Is there a well-defined set of regexes for validating international postal codes? I have 52 different countries that I have to validate against, so I was hoping someone already has this problem licked.

Comment: Don't know about all of them, but www.regexlib.com has a large number of them defined. Check Browse Expressions, under Address..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6409948/469210 for UK postcodes.